# How to add an arrow to menu items has submenus

Tags: php, menus, filters, hooks

I want to add arrow (or anything like ...) after every menu item that have children menus.

I know that there is some JavaScript solutions. But for some reasons (stability and ...), I don't want to use it. Also CSS `.menu-item-has-children:after` selector isn't good for me.

so is there any way I could do it using PHP.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by a PHP solution - this is a styling question. You may want to look into custom nav walkers as they allow you to manipulate markup and add classes if you need to do so.

Comment: Why don't you use a background-image on the `li` element?

Comment: @WebElaine I think he means manually inserting an image with PHP...

Comment: I don't know what is nav Walker. can you explain the solution as an answer? @WebElaine